# Groupby and map lodash keep existing fields

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have following data

```
[
  {
    "supplier_invoice_number": "DTR/12341",
    "contract_id": 789,
    "net_amount": 10000,
    "buyer_price": 10025,
    "net_qty": 8,
    "client_payment_req_id": 3,
    "clientidsupplier": 1,
    "markuptype": 2,
    "buyerclientid": 353,
    "markupvalue": 25
  },
  {
    "supplier_invoice_number": "DTR/119",
    "contract_id": 789,
    "net_amount": 10000,
    "buyer_price": 12500,
    "net_qty": 9,
    "client_payment_req_id": 3,
    "clientidsupplier": 2,
    "markuptype": 1,
    "buyerclientid": 353,
    "markupvalue": 25
  }
]
```

I am using lodash group by and map to get data like this

```
{
buyer_price: 22525
client_payment_req_id: undefined
contract_id: "789"
net_qty: 17
}
```

```js
const Data = [{
    "supplier_invoice_number": "DTR/12341",
    "contract_id": 789,
    "net_amount": 10000,
    "buyer_price": 10025,
    "net_qty": 8,
    "client_payment_req_id": 3,
    "clientidsupplier": 1,
    "markuptype": 2,
    "buyerclientid": 353,
    "markupvalue": 25
  },
  {
    "supplier_invoice_number": "DTR/119",
    "contract_id": 789,
    "net_amount": 10000,
    "buyer_price": 12500,
    "net_qty": 9,
    "client_payment_req_id": 3,
    "clientidsupplier": 2,
    "markuptype": 1,
    "buyerclientid": 353,
    "markupvalue": 25
  }
]
const finalData = _(Data)
  .groupBy('contract_id')
  .map((buyer_price, id) => ({
    client_payment_req_id: buyer_price['client_payment_req_id'],
    contract_id: id,
    buyer_price: _.sumBy(buyer_price, 'buyer_price'),
    net_qty: _.sumBy(buyer_price, 'net_qty'),

  }))
  .value()

console.log(finalData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

But I want all the remaining fields there as well

"client_payment_req_id": 3,
"clientidsupplier": 1,
"markuptype": 2,
"buyerclientid": 353,
"markupvalue": 25

In the final data I want to have remaining fields as well ,but I am not able to include them ,Please help me out here .Thanks

So the final data would look like

```
{
    buyer_price: 22525
    client_payment_req_id: undefined
    contract_id: "789"
    net_qty: 17,
    "client_payment_req_id": 3,
    "clientidsupplier": 1,
    "markuptype": 2,
    "buyerclientid": 353,
    "markupvalue": 25
    }
```

P.s -Assuming All the rest fields would be same in all records

Comment: then just return them in your map?

Comment: How ?? ,its a lodash map

Comment: you are passing the callback to the map function, you have full control on what is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below ,your `buyer_price` is actually an array ,you can keep the first value like i have show below.

```js
const Data = [{
  "supplier_invoice_number": "DTR/12341",
  "contract_id": 789,
  "net_amount": 10000,
  "buyer_price": 10025,
  "net_qty": 8,
  "client_payment_req_id": 3,
  "clientidsupplier": 1,
  "markuptype": 2,
  "buyerclientid": 353,
  "markupvalue": 25
}, {
  "supplier_invoice_number": "DTR/119",
  "contract_id": 789,
  "net_amount": 10000,
  "buyer_price": 12500,
  "net_qty": 9,
  "client_payment_req_id": 3,
  "clientidsupplier": 2,
  "markuptype": 1,
  "buyerclientid": 353,
  "markupvalue": 25
}]
const finalData = _(Data).groupBy('contract_id').map((buyer_price, id) => ({
  client_payment_req_id: buyer_price[0]['client_payment_req_id'],
  buyerclientid: buyer_price[0]['buyerclientid'],
  contract_id: id,
  buyer_price: _.sumBy(buyer_price, 'buyer_price'),
  net_qty: _.sumBy(buyer_price, 'net_qty'),
})).value()

console.log(finalData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```